# showing scroll down text and arrow at a particular location on the image?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, font-awesome

I have an HTML where I have an image on which I want to add this text `SCROLL DOWN` with down arrow so that if I click that `SCROLL DOWN` arrow, it should take me down.

Here is my jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/jgf90mh9/12/

In my jsfiddle I have that `SCROLL DOWN` text but it is not getting shown at the exact location it should be shown (compare with below image) but when I click that arrow it is taking me down so I was able to make that work. Only thing is not working is the exact location where `SCROLL DOWN` and down arrow should be shown.

Technically it should be like in this image: https://s3.postimg.org/gbxn8hkf7/home1.png

As you can see on that image there is a `SCROLL DOWN` text and arrow after that and it is on `iStock` text over that image. I need to put `SCROLL DOWN` text and arrow exactly at same location. How can I do that? **Also I need to match the `SCROLL DOWN` font and arrow size everything as well just like what I have in the above image link.**

Am I supposed to use `font-awesome` here? I am already using `font-awesome` for other purpose in my above jsfiddle.

```css
.scroll-down {
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transition: all .5s ease-in 3s;
  transition: all .5s ease-in 3s;
}

.scroll-down {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 28px;
  left: 55%;
  margin-left: -16px;
  display: block;
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
  background-size: 14px auto;
  border-radius: 50%;
  z-index: 2;
  -webkit-animation: bounce 2s infinite 2s;
  animation: bounce 2s infinite 2s;
  -webkit-transition: all .2s ease-in;
  transition: all .2s ease-in;
}

.scroll-down:before {
  position: absolute;
  top: calc(50% - 8px);
  left: calc(50% - 6px);
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  display: block;
  width: 12px;
  height: 12px;
  content: "";
  border: 2px solid white;
  border-width: 0px 0 2px 2px;
}

section.ok {
  position: relative;
  top: 2000px;
}
```

```html
<div class="top">
  <img id="clipimgA1" class="clippedmain" src="https://s28.postimg.org/tkwg9tmdp/homepage-image-1.png" alt="img">
  <img class="imgA1" src="https://s28.postimg.org/tkwg9tmdp/homepage-image-1.png">

  <section>
    <a href="#" class="scroll-down" address="true">SCROLL DOWN</a>
  </section>
  <section class="ok">
  </section>
</div>
```

Comment: What is your question? Please be more specific... To me it sounds like "Please send the css so that I don't have to write it."

Comment: No that's not what I meant. Problem is `SCROLL DOWN` text is not getting shown at the exact location where it should be shown and it's font and text size should match with what I have in that image. This is what I am not able to replicate.

Comment: Yes, but what exactly do you have problems with? There are thousands of guides on how to position stuff with css. And for the font use `font-size` and `font-family`. If it's some special font use [@font-face](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/using-font-face/)

Answer (score 1):

Edited:

1) set to scroll-down text div the left position to 50% adding the width of your side bar `left: calc(50% + 131px)` than use transform: translateX(calc(-50% - 65.5px)) to center it in the right part of the page.

2) remove the 32px width to the scroll-down text and set it as `width: auto` to prevent wrap on text and remove height property because you needn't to have it set;

3) set the position of the arrow(:before) to `bottom: -10px`(stay 10px below the main div) and set the left position in this way `left: 50%`, than add translate to its transform property like `transform: rotated(-45deg) translateX(-50%);` to center it under the text.

```css
* {
    margin: 0px;
}

body {
    margin: 0px;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}

p,
span,
h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6,
td,
div,
ul,
li {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    text-decoration: none;
    list-style: none;
}

.login {
    position: relative;
 top: -50px;
    z-index: 9999;
 color: white;
 text-decoration: none;
 padding: 0 10px;
 font-size: 13px;
}

.signup {
    position: relative;
 top: -50px;
    z-index: 9999;
 color: white;
 text-decoration: none;
 padding: 0;
 font-size: 13px;
}

.above {
 position: relative;
    z-index: 9999;
 padding: 0 5px;
}
.above li{
  display:inline-block;
}

.fa {
 color: white;
 margin: 5px;
}

img {
    /* Set max width to be 100% of the containing element */
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
}

body .company-bio p {
    font-family: 'agenda';
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    letter-spacing: .18em;
    font-family: 'agenda';
    font-weight: 400;
    color: rgb(254, 254, 255);
}

div.company-bio {}

body .company-bio {
 position: relative;
 top: -42px;
    padding-top: 40px;
    margin-left: 131px;
    /*Added Just now */
    padding-bottom: 40px;
    max-width: 100%;
    background: url("https://s30.postimg.org/l04wudgs1/grey-bar.png");
    padding-left: 140px;
    padding-right: 155px;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-family: "Adelle PE";
}

.top h1 {
    color: #f86d2c;
    font-style: italic;
    font-size: 37px;
}

.top p {
    color: white !important;
    background-color: black;
}

.mission-statements .programs {
    position: relative;
    top: 60px;
    width: 300px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 4px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 19px;
    border-color: #EF7440;
    padding: 25px;
    margin: 25px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    text-shadow: 1.5px 2.598px 7.65px rgba(40, 40, 41, 0.16);
    font-family: "adelle regular";
    color: rgb(40, 40, 41);
    line-height: 1.979;
}

.top h4 {
    font-size: 25px;
    font-family: "ITC Avant Garde Gothic";
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    text-transform: uppercase;
    line-height: 1.792;
    text-align: left;
    -moz-transform: matrix( 1.65479981820633, 0, 0, 1.66565153423699, 0, 0);
    -webkit-transform: matrix( 1.65479981820633, 0, 0, 1.66565153423699, 0, 0);
    -ms-transform: matrix( 1.65479981820633, 0, 0, 1.66565153423699, 0, 0);
    position: absolute;
    left: 684.247px;
    top: 280.77px;
}

.top h2 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 320px;
    left: 450px;
    letter-spacing: .3em;
    font-size: 22px;
    font-family: "Avant Garde", Avantgarde, "Century Gothic", CenturyGothic, AppleGothic, sans-serif;
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    text-transform: uppercase;
    line-height: 1.6;
    text-align: center;
    text-shadow: 0px 3px 6.37px rgba(40, 40, 41, 0.004);
}

body .northmanwild .title {
    /* background-image:url(assets/img/Uploads/insta-pics.png); */
    width: 100%;
    padding-bottom: 40px;
    padding-top: 40px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 37px;
    margin-top: 0px !important;
    margin-bottom: 0px !important;
    font-family: "Adelle PE";
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    font-weight: bold;
    font-style: italic;
    line-height: 1.979;
    text-align: center;
    /*text-shadow: 1.5px 2.598px 7.65px rgba(40, 40, 41, 0.5);
opacity: 100%;
fill: 57%;
*/
}

div.leftBar-bottom {
    background-image: url("https://s17.postimg.org/yvv4w2gmn/nav-background.png");
    float: left;
}

div.northmanwild {
    margin-top: -2px;
    width: 90.1%;
    float: right;
    opacity: 0.8;
    margin-bottom: -7px;
}

body .footer {
    width: 90.3%;
    float: right;
    color: rgb(40, 40, 41);
    padding-top: 30px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    font-weight: normal;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-image: url(assets/img/Uploads/footer-bg.png);
}


/*FIGURE OUT PROBLEM WITH MISSION STATEMENTS*/

body .mission-statements {
    margin-left: 131px;
    padding-bottom: 130px;
    padding-left: 45px;
    padding-right: 45px;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-image: url(assets/img/Uploads/bg-trees.png);
}

body .mission-statements .why {
    padding-top: 40px;
    font-family: "Avant Garde", Avantgarde, "Century Gothic", CenturyGothic, AppleGothic, sans-serif;
    padding-bottom: 40px;
    padding-left: 40px;
    position: relative;
    left: -40px;
    top: 30px;
}

body .mission-statements .how {
    padding-top: 40px;
    font-family: "Avant Garde", Avantgarde, "Century Gothic", CenturyGothic, AppleGothic, sans-serif;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    padding-right: 40px;
}

body .mission-statements .what {
    padding-top: 40px;
    padding-bottom: 40px;
    padding-left: 40px;
    font-family: "Avant Garde", Avantgarde, "Century Gothic", CenturyGothic, AppleGothic, sans-serif;
    position: relative;
    left: -40px;
    top: 30px;
}

body .mission-statements .why pre {
    padding-left: 40px;
}

body .mission-statements .how {
    margin-top: 0px !important;
    padding-right: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px !important;
}


/*.top .imgB1
{
  position: relative;
  top: -225px;
}

*/

.top {
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    margin-bottom: -7px;
}

.imgA1 {
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}

.clippedmain {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}

#clippedImg {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 2;
}

#clipimgA1 {
    /*Chrome,Safari*/
    -webkit-clip-path: polygon(1px 100%, 131px 100%, 130px 0px, 0px 0px);
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 2;
    opacity: 0.5;
}


/*Firefox*/

clip-path: url("#clipPolygon");

/* iOS support inline encoded svg file*/

-webkit-mask: url(data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8;base64,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) no-repeat;

}
.imgB1 {
    position: absolute;
    top: -65px;
    left: 70px;
}
.footer .footer-section1 {
    float: left;
    width: 33%;
}
.footer .footer-section2 .block-title {
    position: relative;
    width: 338px;
    left: -140px;
    font-size: 16px !important;
    font-family: "AvantGarde";
    color: rgb(40, 40, 41);
    /* font-style: italic; */
    
    letter-spacing: 4px;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #000000;
}
.footer .footer-section2 .block-content {
    font-style: italic;
    line-height: 1.52;
    top: 18px;
    left: 52px;
    position: relative;
}
.footer .footer-section3 .block-content {
    position: relative;
    line-height: 1.52;
    left: 12px;
    letter-spacing: 4px;
    top: 15px;
    font-style: italic;
}
.footer .footer-section3 .block-title {
    border-bottom: 2px solid #000000;
    width: 60%;
    left: 14px;
    position: relative;
}
.footer .footer-section1 .block-content {
    position: relative;
    line-height: 1.52;
    top: 67px;
    left: 125px;
    font-style: italic;
}
.footer .footer-section2 {
    position: relative;
    left: -89px;
}
.footer .footer-section2 {
    float: left;
    width: 33%;
}
.footer .footer-section3 {
    float: left;
    width: 33%;
}
.scroll-down {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transition: all .5s ease-in 3s;
    transition: all .5s ease-in 3s;
}
a{
  text-decoration: none !important;
  color: white !important;
}
.scroll-down {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 35px;
    left: calc(50% + 131px);
    transform: translateX(calc(-50% - 65.5px));
    margin-left: -16px;
    display: block;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    background-size: 14px auto;
    border-radius: 50%;
    z-index: 2;
    -webkit-animation: bounce 2s infinite 2s;
    animation: bounce 2s infinite 2s;
    -webkit-transition: all .2s ease-in;
    transition: all .2s ease-in;
}
.scroll-down:before {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -10px;
    left:50%;
    transform: rotate(-45deg) translateX(-50%);
    display: block;
    width: 12px;
    height: 12px;
    content: "";
    border: 2px solid white;
    border-width: 0px 0 2px 2px;
}
section.ok {
    position: relative;
    top: 2000px;
}
.copy-rights {
    font-size: 16px;
    font-family: "Avant Garde", Avantgarde, "Century Gothic", CenturyGothic, AppleGothic, sans-serif;
    position: relative;
    top: 48px;
    display: block;
    font-size: 12px;
    text-align: center;
    color: rgb(40, 40, 41);
    font-style: italic;
    -moz-transform: matrix( 0.99963252426166, 0, 0, 0.99882633931212, 0, 0);
    -webkit-transform: matrix( 0.99963252426166, 0, 0, 0.99882633931212, 0, 0);
    -ms-transform: matrix( 0.99963252426166, 0, 0, 0.99882633931212, 0, 0);
    font-style: normal;
}
#leftBar {
    background-color: #030303;
    box-shadow: 2.996px 0.157px 7.65px 1.35px rgba(40, 40, 41, 0.25);
    border-right: solid #EF7440;
    border-right-width: 4px;
    top: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    height: 2278px;
    position: absolute;
    width: 131px;
    /*Commented today */
    /* opacity: 0.5;  */
}

/*

#holder {
  width: 700px;
   margin-left: 263px;
  padding-left: 50px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  height: 100%;
  float: right;
  position: fixed;

}

*/
@font-face {
    font-family: BEBAS;
    src: url("http://webdesigncove.com/fonts/BEBAS___.ttf")
}
h1.logo {
    font-size: 26px;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    letter-spacing: normal;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    line-height: 1.2em;
    letter-spacing: -3px;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 10px;
}
h1.postTitle {
    font-family: BEBAS, Helvetica, Verdana, Sans-Serif;
}
p {
    font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    letter-spacing: .28em;
    line-height: 1.45em;
}
#navigation {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 3;
}
#navigation li {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}
#navigation a:link {
    font-family: "ITC Avant Garde Gothic";
    font-size: 15px;
    font-style: normal;
}
#navigation a:visited {
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}
#navigation a:hover {
    color: #FE5B1F;
}
.copy-right-text {
    font: Bold 12px 'Open Sans';
    color: #ffffff;
    padding-top: 10px;
    text-align: center;
}
nav ul {
    list-style-type:none;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

nav ul li {
    display:inline-block;
    position:relative;
}

nav ul li a {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 10px;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}
#leftBar{z-index:99;}
/* nav ul li a:hover {
  background: #00648C;
} */

ul.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="top">
    <img id="clipimgA1" class="clippedmain" src="https://s28.postimg.org/tkwg9tmdp/homepage-image-1.png" alt="img">
    <img class="imgA1" src="https://s28.postimg.org/tkwg9tmdp/homepage-image-1.png">

<section>
<a href="#" class="scroll-down" address="true">SCROLL DOWN</a>
</section>
<section class="ok">
</section> 
</div>

 <div id="leftBar">
  <br />

  <svg id="clippedImg" width="0" height="0">
   <clipPath id="clipPolygon">
    <polygon points="1 100%,131 100%,130 0,0 0">
    </polygon>
   </clipPath>
  </svg>
  <nav>
   <ul>
    <li class="dropdown">
     <a href="#"><b>OUR DNA</b> <i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i></a>
     <ul class="dropdown-content">
      <li><a href="#"><i>RISK</i></a></li>
     </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="dropdown">
     <a href="#"><b>PROGRAMS</b> <i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i></a>
     <ul class="dropdown-content">
      <li><a href="#"><i>PROFESSIONAL</i></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><i>ADVENTURE SPORT</i></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><i>ENTERTAINMENT</i></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><i>COLLEGIATE</i></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><i>INDIVIDUAL</i></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><i>COMMERCIAL</i></a></li>
     </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="dropdown">
     <a href="#"><b>RESEARCH</b> <i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i></a>
     <ul class="dropdown-content">
      <li><a href="#"><i>CORPORATE SURVEY</i></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><i>INDIVIDUAL SURVEY</i></a></li>
     </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="dropdown">
     <a href="#"><b>STORIES</b></a>
    </li>    
   </ul>
  </nav>
 </div>


<ul class="above">
    <li><i class="fa fa-facebook-square"></i></li>
    <li><i class="fa fa-twitter-square"></i></li>
    <li><i class="fa fa-instagram"></i></li>
</ul>
<a class="login" href="#">Log In&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;|</a>
<a class="signup" href="#">Sign Up</a>
<div class="leftBar-bottom">

</div>

<!-- End Side bar div-->
<div class="company-bio">
    <p align="center" style="font-family: Adelle PE">Hello World </p>
    <p align="center" style="font-family: Adelle PE">Nice Text! </p>
    <p align="center">Hello David</p>
</div>
```

Comment: I have done exactly that only. I have placed `SCROLL DOWN` in the same div where my image is there. Check my jsfiddle.  Problem is `SCROLL DOWN` text is not getting shown at the exact location where it should be shown and it's font and text size should match with what I have in that image. This is what I am not able to replicate. It should exactly match with what I have in my image.

Comment: check your edited fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/VLK_STUDIO/jgf90mh9/13/ one problem was you set 32px for the scrolldown div so the text was wrapped because it couldn't stay in that space. Another problem was the top position of the arrow placed with a before pseudo. I've edited it.

Comment: by the way I suggest you to not use absolute position for the side-bar. Main template components should be built in relative position.

Comment: thanks got it.. but how can we put `SCROLL DOWN` at the exact location where `iStock` is there. If you look up my image, you will see where it is there? Any thoughts how we can make that work and put it at exact location?

Comment: check my last reviewed answer and try it on the snippet.

Comment: Are you sure? It looks like now scroll down click is not working and also I have arrows on left side bar texts and that is gone too as well?

Comment: sorry maybe I've not understand very well what you need.